# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: profiles_api_userprofile.id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have created a custom model on django to create users and superuser, and now when i try to create a superuser, i get the following error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: profiles_api_userprofile.id`

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Manager for user profiles"""

    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        """Create a new user profile"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email, name=name
        )  # creates a new model that the manager is representing
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password):
        """Create and save a new superuser with given details"""
        user = self.create_user(email, name, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(self._db)

        return user

    # is_superuser is automatically created by PermissionsMixin


class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Database model for users in the system"""

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["name"]

    def get_full_name(self):
        """Retrieve full name of user"""
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Retrieve short name of user"""
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        """Return string representation of our user"""
        return self.email
```

I added the model in the settings.py file as follows `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "profiles_api.UserProfile"`

I tried to delete **pycache** and 0001_initial.py as well as the whole db.sqlite3, and then the following steps:

1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate

But after that when i try to create the superuser, the same error occurs.

The whole Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 61, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 156, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/profiles_api/models.py", line 28, in create_superuser
    user.save(self._db)
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 740, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 777, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 907, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1332, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/django-rest-copy/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: profiles_api_userprofile.id
```

As new to Django Rest Framework, i would b grateful for any help. Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: You work with a signal?

Comment: I am not sure what a signal means

Answer (score 0):

#### Try these steps (i think it's should be working)

```
1- delete (migrations) folder
2- delete database (db.sqlite3)
3- run command (python manage.py makemigrations)
4- run command (python manage.py migrate)
5- now try to create superuser
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when i follow your steps, i get the following error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: profiles_api_userprofile`

Comment: Add dummy = models.charField(max_length=120)

Comment: Then run command migration and migrate